# regular expression minimum word count

Tags: regex

What regex should I use for a minimum word count? This is for a dating website where the user has to describe himself in minimum 50 words. So can allow all punctuation characters, new lines, question marks, numbers and basically anything the user types in as long as it has over 50 words.

I have this `(\b[A-Za-z0-9 '-_]+\b.*){50,}` but it does not let you do new line characters

Thanks

Comment: What is a word for you?

Answer (score 2):

To include newline characters as well use this regex:

```
(\b[A-Za-z0-9\s'_-]+\b){50,}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's a website as you say so, you don't need regex. Though it is not tagged with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), I do suppose you'll find it helpful.
What you can do is

```
var elem = document.getElementById("id of the text input element here");
if(elem.value.split(" ").length < 50) {
   alert("Minimum 50 words please!!");
}
```

Comment: this breaks in the case of strings like "word1,word2"

Comment: @DRC in which world do end users separate word by a comma?

Comment: in every one where you separate a phrase with a comma, without entering a space like I correctly did in this one.

Comment: That comes under punctuations.. the OP has used `\b` which clearly indicates what he is after

Comment: " So can allow all punctuation characters, new lines, question marks, numbers and basically anything the user types in as long as it has over 50 words."

Comment: a Simple solution to your case would be first strip out all punctuation, replace that with single spaces, and count like you did, `elem.value.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "").replace(/\s+/g, " ").split(" ").length`

Answer (score 0):

@DRC your solution does not solve the problem of users entering 50 spaces

I tweaked your solution and got this working for me

```
function min50Words(source, arguments)
    {
        if (arguments.Value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(" ").length < 50) {
            arguments.IsValid = false;
        } else {
            arguments.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
```

This bit

```
.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(" ").length < 50
```

will collapse all spaces into a single space

Thanks for all your help guys